# Filesystem and locale

Tags: c++, android-ndk, locale

I'm trying to build code which uses boost filesystem with NDK (for android).

Everything is okay except the filesystem:

```
libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:911: error: undefined reference to 'std::locale::locale(char const*)'
libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:911: error: undefined reference to 'std::locale::locale(char const*)'
libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:911: error: undefined reference to 'std::locale::locale(char const*)'
libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:911: error: undefined reference to 'std::locale::locale(char const*)'
```

The 911 line of code:

```
static std::locale posix_lazy_initialization(path::imbue(std::locale("")));
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

---

When I changed STL version from: `gnustl_static` to `gnustl_shared` problem disappeared. What could it be?

Comment: I am facing this as well, however shared linkage is not an appropriate solution for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 906/907, they have the MACRO

```
#if defined(BOOST_POSIX_API) && \
    !(defined(macintosh) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__APPLE_CC__))
```

Which I changed to include an exception for ANDROID

```
#if defined(BOOST_POSIX_API) && \
    !(defined(macintosh) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__APPLE_CC__) || defined(ANDROID))
```

So far so good, though my code does not rely on locales...

I have cross posted this question to the Android Developers Google Group, so maybe they will have a definitive answer on why dynamic linking works instead of static. I will post any news I get...

Comment: Thank you for the answer ;) Please, post here if any news.