# Distribute NDK Library with gnustl?

Tags: android, stl, linker, android-ndk, software-distribution

I am developing a library for Android which has both Java and Native components. The Native library depends on the GNU STL. I was linking against `gnustl_static`, but have ran into a few strange problems that were resolved by linking `gnustl_shared`. (for example the question [Filesystem and locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843144/filesystem-and-locale/)). For the time being, I have settled on `gnustl_shared`.

Here's where the question is -- the consumer of my library is expected to link against the Native .so to add code of their own. I understand from reading that all the C-runtimes must match.

1. Demanding my clients use `gnustl_shared` seems like it might not work (as far as diplomacy and ease of integration goes)
2. If I build with `gnustl_shared`, the JAR file generated contains `libgnustl_shared.so`, which causes a problem building an APK which also relies on this library. -- I suppose I can just not include it in the JAR file?
3. If I build against `gnustl_static` do I avoid all these problems?
4. If my API contains refernces to STL objects  (mostly `std::string` and `std::vector`), will I face problems if my clients do not use GNU STL?

thanks